# MS-Azure Linux VM needs several restarts befor SSH connection is possible

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

i have several Linux Vms in MS Azure within the same security group and i can access all of them over SSH expect one. Here i need to restart the VM 5 to 10 times before i also can access it via SSH.
anyone has an idea whats wrong with this VM?

Comment: the VM-Agent is not starting. So after several restarts the agent is suddenly running. I guess that is the error

Comment: You can try to go on Azure portal through console and verify if SSH service is running properly or anything else. Click on your VM name and there is an option console on the left.

Comment: I don't think the VM agent is the problem. The SSH connection does not depend on it if the SSH key is already provision.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem seems specific to this VM alone, you might want to check the VM's [Resource Health](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/resource-health-overview) first. Ensure that the VM reports as being **healthy**. If you have [boot diagnostics enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/boot-diagnostics), verify the VM is not reporting boot errors in the logs.

If that looks clean, you might consider [redeploying the VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/redeploy-to-new-node-windows). This redeploys a VM to another node within Azure, which may correct any underlying networking issues.

Do note that post this operation completes, ephemeral disk data is lost and dynamic IP addresses that are associated with the virtual machine are updated.

Additional troubleshooting guidance can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-ssh-connection).